# PowerPoint Text Change Upon Click

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I have several text boxes.

They say:

```
Fruit 1
Fruit 2
Fruit 3
```

When I click each one, the text should correspondingly change to:

```
Apple
Banana
Dragonfruit
```

When one of them is clicked, I want it to change to the respective text, but the others to remain same.

Is there any way to do this without simply hyper linking a bunch of slides? (that would be 8 slides, btw). I am assuming an alternate method will have to use VBA coding but I would prefer something without.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Trigger animations should do it.  Here's how.

Duplicate the Fruit 1 text box, change the text to Apple.
Move the Apple text box exactly atop Fruit 1 and make sure that it's at least a bit wider than Fruit 1.
Give Apple's shape a fill of Slide Background.
Now add an appear animation to Apple then in the animation pane, timing effects, set it to appear on trigger when you click Fruit 1.

Test to make sure this works right.  Finally, select both text shapes and press Ctrl+D to duplicate them as many times as needed. Change the text in the dupes to Fruit 2/Banana etc.  They'll retain the animation so you don't need to go through all those steps for each of 'em.

[Dusts off hands] My work on this planet is done.

Comment: I didn't know that you could add triggers to animations! Thank you very much!

Comment: Its a shame that MS does not actually have an animation called "Change Text"  my intent would be to use paths which at the end of each animation have the text change....

Comment: @Hightower I'd visit powerpoint.uservoice.com to make this suggestion; it's a good idea. The PPT devs do monitor that site. Meanwhile, a workaround might be to add a second slide identical to the first except that the text has changed and the animated shape holding the text has been moved to the end position of the motion path. Set Advance Slide on the first slide to After: 0 seconds. PPT won't change to the second slide until after the animation on the first slide completes.

Comment: Updating my reply to @Hightower in 2021 for latecomers.  PPT now has a Morph transition that could easily fill the request for text that moves and changes.